# Can not get data from backend after deploying to Netlify

Tags: reactjs, mern, netlify

I have a Mern stack project. It is working in localhost. After deploying to netlify I'm getting errors from my front end.

[image]

The function is giving an error.

```
       axios.get('/api/getbouquets').then((response)=>{
           const data = response.data;
           setBouquets(data);
           setHomeProducts(homeProducts => [...homeProducts, data[0]]);
       }).catch(()=>{
           console.log("data could not fetch from server side")
       });
```

This is my package.json in frontend. I connected to the backend with proxy.

```
{
 "name": "flower-shop-v4",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
 "dependencies": {...

}
```

this is my server.js in the backend

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config()

// Accessing the path module
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const routes = require("./routes/api");

mongoose.connect( process.env.MONGODB_STRING,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
    console.log('Mongoose is connected!');
})

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

app.use("/api", routes);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')))
app.get('/*', (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
})


app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is starting at ${PORT}`));
```

This project was working in Heroku with these settings. But it is not working in netlify. By the way, I looked at MongoDB for the whitelist. All IP is in the whitelist. This issue is not because of that.

edit 1:
[image]

context.js:44 is my error.
context.js:39 is `response.data`. `response.data` is my index.html because I use _redirects in the public folder.

_redirects

```
/* /index.html 200
```

I realized that this is stupid. After deleting redirects, I got 404 errors when frontend try to get data from the backend. Because they are not connected to each other. How can I connect them?

Comment: looks like you're slicing and using map on some array in Home.js, that could be one issue. Apart from that, I'd recommend checking the `response.data`, since, any failing line inside a promise can send it to catch. You can also try `catch(e) => {console.log(e)}`. Share the output of these console logs

Comment: @boxdox I did them and edited the answer. As you said, the problem due to slice method. I tried if(boquets.length !== 0){..}. But it doesn't work. Do you have any idea? by the way, it is still working on heroku.

Comment: Need to check Netlify config file. as you didn't mention that so can't say without it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from netlify support. It is not possible to run this server.js that connect to mongodb in netlify deploy. To connect to MongoDB, I  had to use netlify functions.